# makeevenhead and makeevenfoot

Tags: header-footer, underline

I tried to underline the whole header and footer but I am not capable. Could you give me a hint how this works?

```
 \documentclass[10.5pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek, latin, english, french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pstricks}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{transparent}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\FunctionF(#1){(#1)^3- 3*(#1)}%
\usepackage{url}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Abbildungen}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure} 


\usepackage[breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black, bookmarks=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
left=20mm,right=20mm,
bindingoffset=10mm, top=20mm,bottom=20mm}

\OnehalfSpacing

%%% CHAPTER'S STYLE
\chapterstyle{lyhne}

%%% STYLE OF SECTIONS, SUBSECTIONS, AND SUBSUBSECTIONS
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}

\newcommand{\insertunderline}{\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{.4pt}}

%%% STYLE OF PAGES NUMBERING
\makepagestyle{mypagestyle}
\makeevenfoot{mypagestyle}{November 2016}{\insertunderline}{\thepage}
\makeoddfoot{mypagestyle}{November 2016}{\insertunderline}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{mypagestyle}{Schweizer Jugend Forscht}{\insertunderline}{Potz Blitz - Gewitter in Theorie und Praxis }
\makeoddhead{mypagestyle}{Schweizer Jugend Forscht}{\insertunderline}{Potz Blitz - Gewitter in Theorie und Praxis}

\pagestyle{mypagestyle}


\begin{document}
Hello
\clearpage
Hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: `10.5pt` is not a valid option for `memoir`.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easier to insert a horizontal rule in using the centre header/footer:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand{\insertunderline}{\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{.4pt}}
\newcommand{\insertoverline}{\rule[.8\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{.4pt}}
%%% STYLE OF PAGES NUMBERING
\makepagestyle{mypagestyle}
\makeevenfoot{mypagestyle}{November 2016}{\insertoverline}{\thepage}
\makeoddfoot{mypagestyle}{November 2016}{\insertoverline}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{mypagestyle}{Schweizer Jugend Forscht}{\insertunderline}{Potz Blitz - Gewitter in Theorie und Praxis}
\makeoddhead{mypagestyle}{Schweizer Jugend Forscht}{\insertunderline}{Potz Blitz - Gewitter in Theorie und Praxis}

\pagestyle{mypagestyle}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

However, inserting a rule under/over the header/footer is better achieved using

```
\makeheadrule{<style>}{<width>}{<thickness>}
\makefootrule{<style>}{<width>}{<thickness>}{<skip>}
```

With the above example in mind, you can use the following:

```
%%% STYLE OF PAGES NUMBERING
\makepagestyle{mypagestyle}
\makeevenfoot{mypagestyle}{November 2016}{}{\thepage}
\makeoddfoot{mypagestyle}{November 2016}{}{\thepage}
% Use these if you want the chapter page style to match mypagestyle
\makeevenhead{mypagestyle}{Schweizer Jugend Forscht}{}{Potz Blitz - Gewitter in Theorie und Praxis}
\makeoddhead{mypagestyle}{Schweizer Jugend Forscht}{}{Potz Blitz - Gewitter in Theorie und Praxis}
\makeheadrule{mypagestyle}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makefootrule{mypagestyle}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{\footruleskip}
```

Another thing to remember is that [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) uses the `chapter` page style for every `\chapter`. You may have to change the `chapter` page style as well:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

%%% STYLE OF PAGES NUMBERING
\makepagestyle{mypagestyle}
\makeevenfoot{mypagestyle}{November 2016}{}{\thepage}
\makeoddfoot{mypagestyle}{November 2016}{}{\thepage}
% Use these if you want the chapter page style to match mypagestyle
\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}
\makeoddfoot{chapter}{November 2016}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{mypagestyle}{Schweizer Jugend Forscht}{}{Potz Blitz - Gewitter in Theorie und Praxis}
\makeoddhead{mypagestyle}{Schweizer Jugend Forscht}{}{Potz Blitz - Gewitter in Theorie und Praxis}
\makeheadrule{mypagestyle}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makefootrule{mypagestyle}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{\footruleskip}
\makefootrule{chapter}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{\footruleskip}

\pagestyle{mypagestyle}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

Lorem ipsum

\clearpage

Lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: the heading is perfect but now I have some problems with the footer. can I overline it? And suddenly the layout changes after every second page? is there a solution for this?

Comment: @paris: You'll note that I've used a different page style - `mypagestyle`. However, [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) issues different page styles if you issue a `\chapter`. I'll add some discussion to my answer.